# Java implementation of Spider Solitaire

Tags: java, game, swing, playing-cards

I recently cloned a classical Spider Solitaire game from Microsoft Windows XP. I implemented almost all features of the game. Please tell me anything I can do in order to improve my coding style. Other suggestions are welcome.

The link to resources here: [https://github.com/Marethyu12/JSpider](https://github.com/Marethyu12/JSpider/tree/a65d1253321c10cae2c3e7d484d15cf216d7558f)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

/**
 * JSpider (version: 1.0)
 * By Jimmy Y. (June 25, 2019 to July 3, 2019)
 * 
 * Problems:
 * - After multiple resizings of the component, it freezes to fixed size?
 * 
 * TODO:
 * - Play game 10 times in a row to catch any potential bugs (make sure you say yes to the dialog for new game and try undo, restart, and newGame buttons)
 * - Animations?
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JSpider extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ComponentListener, WindowListener {
    private int width = 1100;
    private int height = 700;

    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    private JMenu menu;

    private JMenuItem newGame;
    private JMenuItem restartGame;
    private JMenuItem undo;
    private JMenuItem deal;
    private JMenuItem changeDifficulty;
    private JMenuItem showStats;
    private JMenuItem toggleDebugMode;
    private JMenuItem howto;
    private JMenuItem about;
    private JMenuItem exit;

    private GameBoard board = null;

    private DataTracker tracker;

    private ImageIcon icon;

    private boolean debug;

    {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private JSpider() {
        super("JSpider");

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menu = new JMenu("Menu");

        newGame = new JMenuItem("New game");
        restartGame = new JMenuItem("Restart current game");
        undo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
        deal = new JMenuItem("Deal!");
        changeDifficulty = new JMenuItem("Change difficulty");
        showStats = new JMenuItem("Show statistics");
        toggleDebugMode = new JMenuItem("Enter debug mode");
        howto = new JMenuItem("How to play?!?");
        about = new JMenuItem("About JSpider");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit window");

        newGame.addActionListener(this);
        restartGame.addActionListener(this);
        undo.addActionListener(this);
        deal.addActionListener(this);
        changeDifficulty.addActionListener(this);
        showStats.addActionListener(this);
        toggleDebugMode.addActionListener(this);
        howto.addActionListener(this);
        about.addActionListener(this);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

        toggleDebugMode.setEnabled(false);

        menu.add(newGame);
        menu.add(restartGame);
        menu.add(undo);
        menu.add(deal);
        menu.add(changeDifficulty);
        menu.add(showStats);
        menu.add(toggleDebugMode);
        menu.add(howto);
        menu.add(about);
        menu.add(exit);

        menuBar.add(menu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        selectDifficulty();
        setContentPane(board);
        board.setInsets(getInsets());

        tracker = new DataTracker("stats.db");

        icon = new ImageIcon(readImage("images\\icon.png"));
        setIconImage(icon.getImage());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        addComponentListener(this);
        addWindowListener(this);

        debug = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JSpider main = new JSpider();
            main.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private Image readImage(String fileName) {
        Image img = null;

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return img;
    }

    private void selectDifficulty() {
        String[] difficulties = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"};
        String choice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Select difficulty:", "New game", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, difficulties, difficulties[0]);

        if (board == null && choice == null) {
            board = new GameBoard("Easy"); // if user does not select any (ie. he cancelled), then easy is defaulted at startup
        } else if (board == null && choice != null) {
            board = new GameBoard(choice);
        } else if (choice != null) {
            board.clearCards();
            board.loadImages(choice);
            board.newGame();
        }

        // else if choice is null then do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source == newGame) {
            board.newGame();
            int[] a = tracker.getData(board.getDifficulty());
            a[3]++;
        } else if (source == restartGame) {
            board.resetGame();
        } else if (source == undo) {
            if (board.canUndo()) { board.undo(); }
        } else if (source == deal) {
            board.deal();
        } else if (source == changeDifficulty) {
            selectDifficulty();
        } else if (source == showStats) {
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, true);

            dialog.setTitle("Statistics");
            dialog.setSize(190, 170);
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

            for (String difficulty : new String[]{"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"}) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                int[] a = tracker.getData(difficulty);

                JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Best Score: " + a[0]);
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Best moves: " + a[1]);
                JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Wins: " + a[2]);
                JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Quits: " + a[3]);

                label1.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                label2.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                label3.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
                label4.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

                JButton button = new JButton("reset all");
                button.addActionListener(evt -> {
                    tracker.resetAll();
                    dialog.dispose();
                });
                button.setAlignmentX(JComponent.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

                panel.add(label1);
                panel.add(label2);
                panel.add(label3);
                panel.add(label4);
                panel.add(button);

                tabbedPane.addTab(difficulty, panel);
            }

            dialog.add(tabbedPane);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } else if (source == toggleDebugMode) {
            debug = !debug;
            toggleDebugMode.setText(debug ? "Exit debug mode" : "Enter debug mode");
        } else if (source == howto) {
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, true);

            dialog.setTitle("Spider solitaire gameplay (shamelessly copied and pasted from Wikipedia)");
            dialog.setSize(500, 400);
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            JEditorPane textRegion = new JEditorPane("text/html", "");

            textRegion.setEditable(false);

            String text = "The game is played with two decks of cards for a total of 104 " +
                          "cards. Fifty-four of the cards are laid out horizontally in ten " +
                          "columns with only the top card showing. The remaining fifty cards " +
                          "are laid out in the lower right hand corner in five piles of ten with " +
                          "no cards showing." +
                          "<p>In the horizontal columns a card may be moved to any other card " +
                          "in the column as long as it is in descending numerical sequence. " +
                          "For example, a six of hearts may be moved to a seven of any suit. " +
                          "However, a sequence of cards can only be moved if they are all of " +
                          "the same suit in numerical descending order. For example, a six " +
                          "and seven of hearts may be moved to an eight of any suit, but a six " +
                          "of hearts and seven of clubs cannot be moved together. Moving the top card in a " +
                          "column allows the topmost hidden card to be turned over. This card then enters " +
                          "into the play. Other cards can be placed on it, and it can be moved to other cards " +
                          "in a sequence or to an empty column.</p>" +
                          "<p>The object of the game is to uncover all the hidden cards and by moving cards " +
                          "from one column to another to place cards in sequential order from King to Ace " +
                          "using the fewest moves. Each final sequence must be all of the same suit. Once a " +
                          "complete sequence is achieved the cards are removed from the table and 100 " +
                          "points are added to the score. Once a player has made all the moves possible with the current card layout, the player draws a new row of cards from one of the piles of ten in the right lower hand corner by " +
                          "clicking on the cards. Each of the ten cards in this draw lands face up on each of the ten horizontal columns and the player then " +
                          "proceeds to place these in such a way to create a sequence of cards all in one suit.</p>";

            textRegion.setText(text);

            dialog.add(new JScrollPane(textRegion));
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } else if (source == about) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "JSpider (version: 1.0)\nThis program is built by Jimmy Y. (codingexpert123@gmail.com)", "About JSpider", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            int[] a = tracker.getData(board.getDifficulty());
            a[3]++;
            tracker.writeToFile();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        width = e.getComponent().getWidth();
        height = e.getComponent().getHeight();

        if (debug) {
            System.err.println("width:" + width + ", height:" + height);
        }

        board.calcYCutoff();
        board.fixPiles();
        board.fixDeck();
        board.fixJunk();
        board.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        int[] a = tracker.getData(board.getDifficulty());
        a[3]++;
        tracker.writeToFile();
    }

    @Override public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
    @Override public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
    @Override public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
    @Override public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    @Override public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    private class GameBoard extends JComponent implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        private final int piles = 10;
        private final int slots = 6; // deck slots, each slot have 10 (piles) cards

        private final int margin = 10;

        private final int cardWidth = 71;
        private final int cardHeight = 96;

        private final Color bgColor = new Color(0, 120, 0);

        private List<Card> allCards; // also it's a junk pile

        private Image cardBack;

        private List<Card>[] pile;
        private List<Card>[] deck;

        private int top; // pointer to top
        private int ptr;

        private int yCutoff;

        private int score;
        private int moves;

        private List<Card> movingPile;

        private int index;

        private int prevMX;
        private int prevMY;

        private String difficulty;

        private Stack<GameState> undoStack;

        private Insets insets;

        public GameBoard(String difficulty) {
            cardBack = readImage("images\\back.png");
            undoStack = new Stack<>();
            insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);

            loadImages(difficulty);
            calcYCutoff();
            newGame();

            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(bgColor);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

            int xGap = (width - piles * cardWidth) / (piles + 1);
            int y = margin;

            for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                int x = xGap + i * cardWidth + i * xGap - insets.left;

                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.fillRect(x, y, cardWidth, cardHeight); // a white rectangle border indicates that there's no cards at that pile
                g.setColor(bgColor);
                g.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, cardWidth - 2, cardHeight - 2);

                pile[i].stream().forEach(card -> {
                    g.drawImage(card.isFaceDown() ? cardBack : card.getImage(), card.x, card.y, this);
                });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
                Card card = deck[i].get(0);
                g.drawImage(cardBack, card.x, card.y, this);
            }

            for (int i = 12; i <= ptr; i += 13) {
                Card card = allCards.get(i);
                g.drawImage(card.getImage(), card.x, card.y, this);
            }

            g.setColor(bgColor.darker());
            g.fillRect(width / 2 - 100 - insets.left, height - cardHeight - margin - insets.bottom - 50, 200, cardHeight);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Score: ").append(score);
            sb.append("\nMoves: ").append(moves);

            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.setFont(new Font("consolas", Font.BOLD, 14));
            drawString(g, sb.toString(), width / 2 - 50, height - cardHeight - margin - insets.bottom - 50 + 25);

            if (movingPile != null) {
                movingPile.stream().forEach(card -> {
                    g.drawImage(card.getImage(), card.x, card.y, this);
                });
            }
        }

        public void setInsets(Insets insets) {
            this.insets = insets;
            repaint();
        }

        public String getDifficulty() {
            return difficulty;
        }

        public void undo() {
            GameState state = undoStack.pop();

            allCards = state.getAllCards();
            pile = state.getPile();
            top = state.getTop();
            ptr = state.getPtr();

            repaint();

            score--;
            moves++;

            if (!canUndo()) {
                undo.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        public boolean canUndo() {
            return !undoStack.empty() && !undoStack.peek().dealed();
        }

        public void resetGame() {
            if (undoStack.empty()) {
                return;
            }

            while (undoStack.size() > 1) {
                undoStack.pop();
            }

            GameState state = undoStack.pop();

            allCards = state.getAllCards();
            pile = state.getPile();
            deck = state.getDeck();
            top = state.getTop();
            ptr = state.getPtr();

            repaint();

            score = 500;
            moves = 0;

            undo.setEnabled(false);
        }

        public void clearCards() {
            collectAllCards();
            allCards = null;
        }

        /*
         * This method is an extension of Graphics::drawString, it handles strings with newlines, thanks to SO!
         */
        private void drawString(Graphics g, String str, int x, int y) {
            for (String line : str.split("\n")) {
                g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
            }
        }

        private void deal() {
            for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                Card card = deck[top].get(i);
                pile[i].add(card);
                card.flip();
                fixPile(i);
            }

            deck[top--] = null;
            undoStack.push(new GameState());
            undo.setEnabled(false);

            repaint();
        }

        public void calcYCutoff() {
            yCutoff = height * 3 / 5;
        }

        public void fixJunk() {
            int y = height - cardHeight - margin - 40 - insets.bottom - 16;

            for (int i = 0; i <= ptr; i++) {
                Card card = allCards.get(i);

                card.y = y;
            }
        }

        public void fixDeck() {
            int y = height - cardHeight - margin - 40 - insets.bottom - 16;

            for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
                int x = width - cardWidth - margin - insets.left - 10 - (margin + 2) * i;

                deck[i].stream().forEach(card -> {
                    card.x = x;
                    card.y = y;
                });
            }
        }

        public void fixPiles() {
            for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                fixPile(i);
            }
        }

        private void fixPile(int index) {
            if (pile[index].size() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            int xGap = (width - piles * cardWidth) / (piles + 1);
            int topX = xGap + index * cardWidth + index * xGap - insets.left;
            int yGap = 35;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                int cards = pile[index].size();

                Card prevCard = null;

                yGap -= (i < 4) ? 4 : 1;

                for (int j = 0; j < cards; j++) {
                    Card card = pile[index].get(j);

                    int topY = (prevCard == null) ? margin : prevCard.y + (prevCard.isFaceDown() ? margin : yGap);

                    card.x = topX;
                    card.y = topY;

                    prevCard = card;
                }

                int lastY = pile[index].get(pile[index].size() - 1).y;

                if (lastY < yCutoff) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void collectAllCards() {
            if (allCards.size() < 104) {
                for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                    int cards = pile[i].size();

                    for (int j = 0; j < cards; j++) {
                        Card card = pile[i].get(j);

                        if (!card.isFaceDown()) {
                            card.flip();
                        }

                        allCards.add(card);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
                    List<Card> slot = deck[i];

                    int size = slot.size();

                    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                        allCards.add(slot.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * preconditions:
         * - undoStack is !null
         * - loadImages() is called
         * - calcYCutoff() is called, otherwise fixPile() will be slow
         */
        public void newGame() {
            collectAllCards();
            Collections.shuffle(allCards);
            initDeck();
            initPiles();
            deal();
            undoStack.clear();
            undo.setEnabled(false);

            ptr = -1;
            score = 500;
            moves = 0;
            movingPile = null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private void initDeck() {
            deck = new List[slots];

            top = slots - 1;

            int y = height - cardHeight - margin - 40 - insets.bottom - 16;

            for (int i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
                deck[i] = new ArrayList<>();

                int x = width - cardWidth - margin - insets.left - 10 - (margin + 2) * i;

                for (int j = 0; j < piles; j++) {
                    Card card = draw();

                    card.x = x;
                    card.y = y;
                    card.width = cardWidth;
                    card.height = cardHeight;

                    deck[i].add(card);
                }
            }
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private void initPiles() {
            pile = new List[piles];

            for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                pile[i] = new ArrayList<>();

                int cards = (i < 4) ? 5 : 4;

                for (int j = 0; j < cards; j++) {
                    Card card = draw();

                    card.width = cardWidth;
                    card.height = cardHeight;

                    pile[i].add(card);
                }

                fixPile(i);
            }
        }

        private Card draw() {
            Card card = allCards.get(0);
            allCards.remove(card);
            return card;
        }

        public void loadImages(String difficulty) {
            this.difficulty = difficulty;

            int value = -1;

            if (difficulty.equals("Easy")) {
                value = 4;
            } else if (difficulty.equals("Medium")) {
                value = 3;
            } else {
                value = 1;
            }

            allCards = new ArrayList<>();

            int counter = 0;

            while (counter < 8) {
                for (int suit = value; suit <= 4; suit++) {
                    for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) {
                        allCards.add(new Card(readImage("images\\" + rank + "" + suit + ".png"), suit, rank, true));
                    }

                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void showPlayAgainDialog() {
            int[] a = tracker.getData(difficulty);

            a[0] = Math.max(a[0], score);
            a[1] = a[1] == 0 ? moves : Math.min(a[1], moves);
            a[2]++;

            int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Do you want to play again?", "Game over! You won!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (resp == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                newGame();
            } else {
                tracker.writeToFile();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        private boolean checkForCardsToRemove(int index) {
            int suit = -1;
            int rank = 1;

            for (int i = pile[index].size() - 1; i >= 0 && rank <= 13; i--, rank++) {
                Card card = pile[index].get(i);

                if (suit == -1) { suit = card.getSuit(); }
                if (suit != card.getSuit()) { return false; }
                if (card.isFaceDown()) { return false; }
                if (card.getRank() != rank) { return false; }
            }

            if (rank == 14) {
                int y = height - cardHeight - margin - 40 - insets.bottom - 16;

                Card prevCard = (ptr == -1) ? null : allCards.get(ptr);

                for (int i = pile[index].size() - 1; i >= 0 && --rank >= 1; i--) {
                    Card card = pile[index].get(i);

                    card.x = (prevCard == null) ? margin : prevCard.x + margin + 2;
                    card.y = y;
                    card.flip(); // the card must be flipped face down for new game

                    pile[index].remove(card);
                    allCards.add(card);
                    ptr++;
                }

                Card last = (pile[index].size() > 0) ? pile[index].get(pile[index].size() - 1) : null;

                if (last != null && last.isFaceDown()) {
                    last.flip();
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();

            prevMX = mouseX;
            prevMY = mouseY;

            int index = -1;
            int startFrom = -1;

            outer:
            for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                int cards = pile[i].size();

                for (int j = cards - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    Card card = pile[i].get(j);

                    if (card.contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                        index = i;
                        startFrom = j;
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (index != -1) {
                if (pile[index].get(startFrom).isFaceDown()) {
                    return;
                }

                List<Card> touched = pile[index].subList(startFrom, pile[index].size()).stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)); // I know it's ugly but it resolves ConcurrentModificationException

                if (!debug) {
                    int suit = -1; // ensures that the selected cards have same suite
                    int rank = -1; // ensures that the selected cards follow decreasing numerical order

                    int size = pile[index].size() - startFrom;

                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, rank--) {
                        if (suit == -1) { suit = touched.get(i).getSuit(); }
                        if (rank == -1) { rank = touched.get(i).getRank(); }
                        if (suit != touched.get(i).getSuit()) { return; }
                        if (rank != touched.get(i).getRank()) { return; }
                    }
                }

                undoStack.push(new GameState(allCards, pile, deck, top, ptr));
                pile[index].removeAll(touched);
                movingPile = touched;
                this.index = index;

                repaint();
            } else if (top >= 0) {
                Card topCard = deck[top].get(0);
                Card botCard = deck[0].get(0);

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(topCard.x, topCard.y, botCard.x + botCard.width - topCard.x, topCard.height);

                if (rect.contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
                    // make sure that there's no empty piles
                    for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                        if (pile[i].size() == 0) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    deal();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (movingPile != null) {
                boolean success = false;

                Card firstCard = movingPile.get(0);
                Card lastCard = movingPile.get(movingPile.size() - 1);

                Rectangle dragRegion = new Rectangle(firstCard.x, firstCard.y, firstCard.width, lastCard.y + lastCard.height - firstCard.y);

                for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                    if (i == index) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Card card = (pile[i].size() > 0) ? pile[i].get(pile[i].size() - 1) : null; // last card

                    if (card != null && card.intersects(dragRegion) && (!debug ? (card.getRank() == firstCard.getRank() + 1) : true)) {
                        pile[i].addAll(movingPile);

                        if (checkForCardsToRemove(i)) {
                            score += 100;

                            if (allCards.size() == 104) {
                                movingPile = null;
                                repaint();
                                showPlayAgainDialog();
                            }
                        }

                        fixPile(i);
                        success = true;
                        break;
                    } else if (card == null && pile[i].size() == 0) {
                        int xGap = (width - piles * cardWidth) / (piles + 1);
                        int topX = xGap + i * cardWidth + i * xGap - insets.left;

                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(topX, margin, cardWidth, cardHeight); // white rectangle border

                        if (rect.intersects(dragRegion)) {
                            pile[i].addAll(movingPile);
                            fixPile(i);
                            success = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!success) {
                    pile[index].addAll(movingPile);
                    undoStack.pop();
                } else {
                    Card last = (pile[index].size() > 0) ? pile[index].get(pile[index].size() - 1) : null;

                    if (last != null && last.isFaceDown()) {
                        last.flip();
                    }

                    score--;
                    moves++;

                    undo.setEnabled(true);
                }

                fixPile(index);
                movingPile = null;

                repaint();

                if (allCards.size() == 104) {
                    showPlayAgainDialog();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (movingPile != null) {
                int mouseX = e.getX();
                int mouseY = e.getY();

                int dx = mouseX - prevMX;
                int dy = mouseY - prevMY;

                movingPile.stream().forEach(c -> c.translate(dx, dy));

                prevMX = mouseX;
                prevMY = mouseY;

                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}

        private class GameState {
            private List<Card> allCards;

            private List<Card>[] pile;
            private List<Card>[] deck;

            private int top;
            private int ptr;

            private boolean dealed;

            public GameState() {
                dealed = true;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public GameState(List<Card> allCards, List<Card>[] pile, List<Card>[] deck, int top, int ptr) {
                this.allCards = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Card card : allCards) {
                    this.allCards.add((Card) card.clone());
                }

                this.pile = new List[piles];

                for (int i = 0; i < piles; i++) {
                    this.pile[i] = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Card card : pile[i]) {
                        this.pile[i].add((Card) card.clone());
                    }
                }

                this.deck = new List[slots];

                for (int i = 0; i < slots; i++) {
                    if (deck[i] == null) {
                        this.deck[i] = null;
                    } else {
                        this.deck[i] = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (Card card : deck[i]) {
                            this.deck[i].add((Card) card.clone());
                        }
                    }
                }

                this.top = top;
                this.ptr = ptr;

                dealed = false;
            }

            public List<Card> getAllCards() {
                return allCards;
            }

            public List<Card>[] getPile() {
                return pile;
            }

            public List<Card>[] getDeck() {
                return deck;
            }

            public int getTop() {
                return top;
            }

            public int getPtr() {
                return ptr;
            }

            public boolean dealed() {
                return dealed;
            }
        }
    }

    private class DataTracker {
        private String fileName;

        private Map<String, int[]> map;

        public DataTracker(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            map = new TreeMap<>();
            readData();
        }

        public void resetAll() {
            for (String difficulty : new String[]{"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"}) {
                int[] a = getData(difficulty);
                Arrays.fill(a, 0);
            }
        }

        public void writeToFile() {
            try {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));

                for (String difficulty : new String[]{"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"}) {
                    int[] a = getData(difficulty);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        dos.writeInt(a[i]);
                    }
                }

                dos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        public int[] getData(String difficulty) {
            return map.get(difficulty);
        }

        private void readData() {
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName)));

                for (String difficulty : new String[]{"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"}) {
                    map.put(difficulty, new int[]{dis.readInt(), dis.readInt(), dis.readInt(), dis.readInt()});
                }

                dis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    private class Card extends Rectangle {
        private Image cardImage;

        private int suit;
        private int rank;

        private boolean isFaceDown;

        public Card(Image cardImage, int suit, int rank, boolean isFaceDown) {
            super();
            this.cardImage = cardImage;
            this.suit = suit;
            this.rank = rank;
            this.isFaceDown = isFaceDown;
        }

        public void flip() {
            isFaceDown = !isFaceDown;
        }

        public Image getImage() {
            return cardImage;
        }

        public int getSuit() {
            return suit;
        }

        public int getRank() {
            return rank;
        }

        public boolean isFaceDown() {
            return isFaceDown;
        }

        @Override
        public Object clone() {
            Card copy = new Card(cardImage, suit, rank, isFaceDown);

            copy.x = x;
            copy.y = y;
            copy.width = width;
            copy.height = height;

            return copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with cloning the game and implementing features? Is this your code or a mix of existing with your code?

Comment: @dfhwze I coded everything by myself.

Comment: Nice job. Just a quick note: "Restart current game" freezes the application.

Comment: @JoachimRohde How? It works fine on my computer (Windows)

Comment: @JimmyYang I just checked it again and it worked now. The time I wrote that I had played several games and after trying to restart the game I had to close the application because it was not reacting at all anymore.